# Connecting to mysqli from inside php function

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having trouble connecting to my database from within a function. I am getting the following error:

"Warning: mysqli::query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in..."

I am using "global", so I don't see what I'm doing wrong.

-- FILE: db.php --

```
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $sql_us, $sql_us_pwd, $sql_db); // Connects fine
```

-- FILE: functions.php --

```
function db_query($query, $type = 'assoc') {

  global $db;
  $result = $db->query($query);

  if ($type == 'assoc') {
    $rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  } else { 
    $rows = $result->fetch_object();
  }

  return $rows;
  mysqli_free_result($result);

}
```

-- FILE: somepage.php --

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$users = db_query($query);
```

Comment: are you including db.php and functions.php on somepage.php ?

Comment: do you use `global $db;` before setting $db?

Comment: @Maximus2012: Yes, I am including the two pages on somepage.php. Other functions which do not require a db connection work fine.

Comment: @PatrickEvans: I tried that earlier and it didn't fix anything.

Comment: use var_dump($query) in your db_query function, for some reason mysqli::query is seeing $query as an object, confirm that var_dump($query) shows it as an object or string.

Comment: You could also try [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to locate the root of the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is working fine for me:

```
// db.php
$db = new mysqli($hostname, $sql_us, $sql_us_pwd, $sql_db); // Connects fine

// functions.php
include_once('db.php');

function db_query($query, $type = 'assoc') {
    global $db;
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if ($type == 'assoc') {
        $rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    } else { 
       $rows = $result->fetch_object();
    }

   return $rows;
   mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// somepage.php
include_once('functions.php');

$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$users = db_query($query);

var_dump($users);
```

They are all in the same directory. Also, I tried it with one of my tables since I don't have the users table.

Comment: this is not exactly an answer, his problem is that he seems to be passing an object to the mysqli::query function somewhere in his code instead of an actual query string

Comment: but then shouldn't I be getting that error also? Unless there is some other code that the OP hasn't posted here.

Comment: That is what i am thinking, is that he hasnt posted some code, as the error is specifically showing that hes passing an object instead of a string.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you.

```
function db_query($query, $db, $type = 'assoc') {

  $result = $db->query($query);

  if ($type == 'assoc') {
    $rows = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
  } else { 
    $rows = $result->fetch_object();
  }

  return $rows;
  mysqli_free_result($result);

}

$db = new mysqli($hostname, $sql_us, $sql_us_pwd, $sql_db); // Connects fine
$query = "SELECT * FROM `users`";
$users = db_query($query,$db);
```

$db connection is not passed to the function so the parameter is not passed to the query function of mysql, there for you are getting the error.

Comment: he has global $db; so the $db is global so its automatically included., and the error is for the mysqli::query function not the $db variable. If it was the $db variable he would be getting an Undefined variable error.

Comment: I tried passing `$db` to the function every single time, which works, but I should not have to if I declare it as a "global" inside the function. I'm trying to avoid passing `$db` every single time I use the function.